# defining properly the notion of "class (or type) of quadrilaterals"?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, education

Many people and teachers have their own idea about what are "the" classes of quadrilaterals, and they are not the same for everyone! Is it possible to explain what can be called a class of quadrilaterals? So far, I have not found anything else than lists of classes - some of them being "special" (?), "important" (??), "particular" (???). Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Could you please name two inconsistent classifications?

Comment: Where are you seeing "special", "important", and "particular" as *classifications* of quadrilaterals?

Comment: @Gae the question of consistency is mainly related to the hierarchy/partitional point of view. But that is not what I wanted to say. There are classes that are always  quoted (squares, rectangles), some are usual but sometimes do not appear (e.g. kites), some are quoted but do not appear in a hierarchy (right trapezoid), some are quite rarely used (inscribed quadrilateral), and so on.

Comment: @Blue everywhere! (say, in the books) you can find adjectives like this but they are never explained.

Comment: @MathieuDity: Without context, it's hard to say, but I suspect adjectives like "important" you've encountered are just that ... *adjectives* ... used by the author to make some point or other about the topic at hand. (Mathematicians are allowed to use common language, after all.) There's no mathematical class of "important quadrilaterals".